# Duality of $\mathcal M(X)$ with $C_0(X)$ and with $C_b(X)$

Tags: measure-theory, dual-spaces, optimal-transport

In the book Optimal Transport for Applied Mathematicians, the author states that if $X$ is separable and locally compact, then the space of finite signed measures $\mathcal M(X)$ is dual to $C_0(X)$. Then, he goes on to claim that one can also establish a duality with $C_b(X)$. He then says that only if $X$ is compact one can claim that $C_0(X) = C_b(X)$.

My question is then, when $X$ is not compact, how come $\mathcal M(X)$ is dual with both $C_0(X)$ and $C_b(X)$? What am I missing?

Comment: The dual of $C_0^\infty(X)$ and $C^\infty_b(X)$ is respectively not the space of all measures. It will be the space of Radon measures or finite measures. Details are given by the Riesz-Markov theorem, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem

Comment: Ok. I fixed the question. Still, I don’t understand the issue t hand.